# Spell-checking SpecFlow feature files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, spell-checking, specflow

Is there a Spell Checker (like http://etherealcode.com/respeller/ or http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7c8341f1-ebac-40c8-92c2-476db8d523ce) that could check the spelling in SpecFlow feature files inside Visual Studio?  I've got ReSharper along with ReSpeller installed, but it does not seem to spell-check anything in my .feature files...

Answer (score 1):

I use [Visual Studio Spell Checker](http://vsspellchecker.codeplex.com/) for spell checking feature files (note that you can also find it in the "Extension Manager" online gallery).

Here's the description from the website:

> This extension provides spell checking support for various "natural
>   language" portions of files.  This includes:
>
> ```
> * Plain text files (the entire file is spell checked)
> * Source code (comments and strings are spell checked)
> * HTML/ASP (things that aren't HTML tags are spell checked)
> ```

Custom dictionaries can also be added to spell check in different languages (e.g. OpenOffice versions 2, 3, and 4 dictionaries).

Comment: Do you by any chance know if this extension can live side by side with  ReSpeller (that works alongside with ReSharper)? I mean -- I'd like to  have ReSpeller spellcheck my C# code and Visual Studio Spell Checker to check the non-C#/XML/etc. files. I'm afraid these two guys will be stepping on each other toes when living together in my VS...

Comment: I'd guess that they can co-exist together. It's free to download so try it out.

Comment: @user3346684 Did you try it?

Comment: Visual Studio Spell Checker works fine for me with *.feature files in VS2017 and VS2019 :)

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen one in VS, but that doesn't necessarily mean that is a problem.

Let's consider how you create your scenarios and features. In best practice, these are created from a conversation between the stakeholder and the developer. Think if it, if you like, as akin to *pair-programming*, this is *pair-specification design*. This process would start with a verbal conversation and only as we find common understanding do we then reach for a tool to record this.

Since features are just plain-text specification files then there are many tools that can record this. To me, VS feels a little one-sided in favour of the developer. Why not be more partisan and instead use email so you can both use its spell-checker and send both parties a copy of exactly what was agreed upon? Maybe use Word, or any other tool that can save as plain-text.

Comment: Yeah, it seems reasonable, yet for me as a developer it would be quitу handy being able to spell check the scenarios I'm editing in VS, without having to use external tools.

Comment: I like this way of thinking. Before a test is accepted as a test and ready to be implemented in code, both parties should agree on that it covers what it should. Only thing is, like you said, that is in best practice. In 'real life' this is hardly the case. The requirements are often well discussed, but the tests are totally up to the developer(s) to make and check.

Comment: Actually where I work right now, the BAs deliver us the Gherkins :-)